# Pad with asterisks in printf?

Tags: c, printf

I've searched high and low, but in printf in C it seems that there's only zero fill and white space fill. I'm looking to write my own fill, in this case using the asterisk.

For example,

Assuming a width of 8 character.

Input: `123`
Ouput: `**123.00`

Input: `3`
Output: `****3.00`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to print into a buffer using `snprintf()` with space padding, then replace the spaces with asterisks afterwards:

```
void print_padded(double n)
{
    char buffer[9];
    char *p;

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "% 8.2f", n);
    for (p = buffer; *p == ' '; p++)
        *p = '*';
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used sprintf though, since ANSI C did not have snprintf implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The following program shows one way of doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void padf (size_t sz, int padch, char *fmt, ...) {
    int wid;
    va_list va;

    // Get the width that will be output.

    va_start (va, fmt);
    wid = vsnprintf (NULL, 0, fmt, va);
    va_end (va);

    // Pad if it's shorter than desired.

    while (wid++ <= sz)
        putchar (padch);

    // Then output the actual thing.

    va_start (va, fmt);
    vprintf (fmt, va);
    va_end (va);
}

int main (void) {
    padf (8, '*', "%.2f\n", 123.0);
    padf (8, '*', "%.2f\n", 3.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Simply call `padf` the same way you would call `printf` but with extra leading width and padding character arguments, and changing the "real" format to preclude leading spaces or zeros, such as changing `%8.2f` to `%.2f`.

It will use the standard variable arguments stuff to work out the actual width of the argument then output enough padding characters to pad that to your desired width before outputting the actual value. As per your requirements, the output of the above program is:

```
**123.00
****3.00
```

Obviously, this solution pads on the left - you could make it more general and pass whether you want it left or right padded (for numerics/strings) but that's probably beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: You need to do `va_end(va);` after the `vsnprintf()` and a new `va_start(va, fmt);` before the `vprintf()`.

Comment: C99 §7.15 ¶3 '_[...] If access to the varying arguments is
desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally referred to as ap in this
subclause) having type va_list._ **The object ap may be passed as an argument to
another function; if that function invokes the va_arg macro with parameter ap, the
value of ap in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the va_end
macro prior to any further reference to ap**.'

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, I ended up finding it in C99 and the C1x draft, which is why I removed my questioning comment. Then I fixed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a string using `snprintf`, and then check it's length.  For any characters that haven't been filled, output an asterik before printing the actual buffer that was filled by `snprintf`.

So for instance:

```
#define STRINGSIZE 8

char buffer[STRINGSIZE + 1];
int length = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%#.2f", floating_point_value);

for (int i = STRINGSIZE - length; i > 0; i--)
{
    printf("*");
}

printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: `snprintf()` will tell you how many characters it wrote (or would have written had there been enough space), so you don't need to call the non-standard `strlength()` ... did you mean `strlen()`?